# blacklist specific url using iptables on linux

Tags: iptables

I am able to blacklist domain/ipaddress using the below commands like for stackoverflow.com on ubuntu

```
iptables -N mychain;
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j mychain;
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j mychain;
iptables -A mychain -m string --algo bm --string "stackoverflow.com" -j DROP
```

OR

```
iptables -A mobicontrol -d stackoverflow.com -j REJECT
```

Question: if I have to block "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" not the stackoverflow.com so how I can block this particular url only. I have tried using string algos like

```
iptables -A mychain -m string --algo bm --string "stackoverflow.com/questions" -j DROP
or
iptables -A mychain -m string --algo bm --string "questions" -j DROP
```

but not able to block "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"
and stackoverflow.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

iptables work on layers 3/4 of the OSI. i.e. block access to certain ips and ports. What you are asking for is url filtering.

iptables cannot be used to perform URL filtering.

You can use a proxy like [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/) to filter out certain URL's.

[1][https://tinyproxy.github.io/]

Comment: What i can use in that case for url filtering

Comment: you may use tinyproxy to do this. I have added their github location in the answer.

Comment: is there is no way by using iptables , we cannot do url filtering.

Comment: Please suggest if i can use any string extension/algo to overcome url filtering or any work around , how i can achive  url filtering using iptables

Comment: there is no way to perform url filtering with ip tables.